# Issue with MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets

Tags: variables, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I am trying to build with msbuild.

The following lines are present in  MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Target

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath Condition="'$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
     <MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>$([MSBUILD]::Unescape($(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll))</MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>
</PropertyGroup>
```

During build I am printing the value of

`MSBuildCommunityTasksPath`,`MSBuildExtensionsPath` and `MSBuildExtensionsPath`.

The values are  :

```
 MSBuildExtensionsPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild
 MSBuildCommunityTasksPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks
 MSBuildCommunityTasksLib: \MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll
```

Why is  MSBuildCommunityTasksLib not getting the value

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll`

Comment: Which version of msbuild.exe are you invoking?

Comment: MSBuild Community Tasks 1.4 is installed.

Comment: I'm asking about the version of Msbuild.exe....example ( C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the UNESCAPE may be throwing you for a loop.

Try the simpler:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath Condition="'$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll</MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>
  </PropertyGroup>
```